# Python AttributeError

Tags: python

```
# Process the data by running the function we wrote above.
station_data = ['201402_station_data.csv']
trip_in = ['201309_trip_data.csv']
trip_out = '201309_trip_summary.csv'
summarise_data(trip_in, station_data, trip_out)

# Load in the data file and print out the first few rows
sample_data = pd.read_csv(trip_out)
display(sample_data.head())​
# Verify the dataframe by counting data points matching each of the time
features.question_3(sample_data)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-568a9b76d0da> in <module>()
       3 trip_in = ['201309_trip_data.csv']
       4 trip_out = '201309_trip_summary.csv'
       5 summarise_data(trip_in, station_data, trip_out)
       6 
       7 # Load in the data file and print out the first few rows

       <ipython-input-6-8a5a5140f3e9> in summarise_data(trip_in,     
       station_data, trip_out)
       30### Question 3a: Add a mathematical operation below   ###
       31### to convert durations from seconds to minutes.     ###
       32new_point['duration'] = float(row['Duration']). ________
       33 
       34# reformat datestrings into multiple columns
       enter code here
       AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '________'
```

Comment: The key step to success in any test is to understand the task. Here it looks like you should fill in something in and you didn't.

Comment: What is this: `new_point['duration'] = float(row['Duration']). ________`?

Comment: What is your question? What is this code supposed to do? How is the error message related to the code fragment that you posted?

Comment: I add new_point['duration'] = float(row['Duration'])/60.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error is in line 32: `32new_point['duration'] = float(row['Duration']). ________`  Your code type casts the value of `row['duration']` to a float, and then calls the attribute/ or method with a period ( `.` ).  There is no float attribut `'________'`, which is in your code.  As Klaus D pointed out, it looks like you are using a template, and did not fill in the values as you were supposed to.  If you can read the template instructions more thoroughly or post more of your code here, you may get some better support.

It looks like this is all in the function, `summarise_data()`, so you should probably write more context from that function if you ask for more help.

Comment: _"Question 3a: Add a mathematical operation below to convert durations from seconds to minutes."_, "template" is an understatement.

Answer (score -1):

```
def summarise_data(trip_in, station_data, trip_out):
"""
This function takes trip and station information and outputs a new
data file with a condensed summary of major trip information. The
trip_in and station_data arguments will be lists of data files for
the trip and station information, respectively, while trip_out
specifies the location to which the summarized data will be written.
"""
# generate dictionary of station - city mapping
station_map = create_station_mapping(station_data)

with open(trip_out, 'w') as f_out:
    # set up csv writer object        
    out_colnames = ['duration', 'start_date', 'start_year',
                    'start_month', 'start_hour', 'weekday',
                    'start_city', 'end_city', 'subscription_type']        
    trip_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames = out_colnames)
    trip_writer.writeheader()

    for data_file in trip_in:
        with open(data_file, 'r') as f_in:
            # set up csv reader object
            trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

            # collect data from and process each row
            for row in trip_reader:
                new_point = {}

                # convert duration units from seconds to minutes
                ### Question 3a: Add a mathematical operation below   ###
                ### to convert durations from seconds to minutes.     ###
                new_point['duration'] = float(row['Duration'])/60
                # reformat datestrings into multiple columns
                ### Question 3b: Fill in the blanks below to generate ###
                ### the expected time values.                         ###
                trip_date = datetime.strptime(row['Start Date'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
                new_point['start_year']  = trip_date.strftime('%Y')
                new_point['start_month'] = trip_date.strftime('%m')
                new_point['start_hour']  = trip_date.strftime('%H')
                new_point['weekday']     = trip_date.strftime('%A')

                # remap start and end terminal with start and end city
                new_point['start_city'] = station_map[row['Start Terminal']]
                new_point['end_city'] = station_map[row['End Terminal']]
                # two different column names for subscribers depending on file
                if 'Subscription Type' in row:
                    new_point['subscription_type'] = row['Subscription Type']
                else:
                    new_point['subscription_type'] = row['Subscriber Type']

                # write the processed information to the output file.
                trip_writer.writerow(new_point)


    # Process the data by running the function we wrote above.
    station_data = ['201402_station_data.csv']
    trip_in = ['201309_trip_data.csv']
    trip_out = '201309_trip_summary.csv' 
    summarise_data(trip_in, station_data, trip_out)

    # Load in the data file and print out the first few rows
    sample_data = pd.read_csv(trip_out)
    display(sample_data.head())

    # Verify the dataframe by counting data points matching each of the      
    time features.
```

[image]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.